# How to sort multiple array based on an array swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, nsdate

I would like to sort multiple array based on an array which is array of NSDate

```
var date = [NSDate]()
var name = [String]()
var job = [String]()
```

i would like to sort name and job based on the date. Example Like

```
date = [2016-04-02 01:03:42 +00002,2016-03-02 01:03:42 +0000,2016-05-02 01:03:42 +0000] 

name = [john,alex,danson]

job = [engineer,programmer,swimmer]
```

i would like to sort the date from oldest to the latest then i would like to sort the name and job based on the date . Result Will be Like

```
date = [2016-03-02 01:03:42 +0000 ,2016-04-02 01:03:42 +0000 , 2016-05-02 01:03:42 +0000 ] //Being Sorted
name = [alex,john,danson]
job = [programmer,engineer,swimmer]
```

How can i do it ?

Comment: is this school homework?

Comment: actually is my project

Comment: Combine them into an array of tuple or encapsulate them as struct  makes more sense.

Comment: how can i do that  ? can you show me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extension NSDate {
    var day: Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.Day, fromDate: self).day }
}

let result = zip(zip(date, name), jobs).map { ($0.0.0, $0.0.1, $0.1) }.sort { $0.0.day < $1.0.day }
print(result)
```

This should do it. If you need an explanation, I'll try to explain.

If you want your existing array's to be sorted:

```
name = name.enumerate().sort { date[$0.index].day < date[$1.index].day }.map { $0.element }
jobs = jobs.enumerate().sort { date[$0.index].day < date[$1.index].day }.map { $0.element }
```

However, doing this is not safe because if the size of `name` or `jobs` is bigger than `date`, it will crash. You'll have to build some safety inside before using this.

What I forgot to mention is, you could also get the "original" arrays sorted by extracting it from `result`:

```
name = result.map { $0.1 }
jobs = result.map { $0.2 }
```

Comment: I kinda understand but do date ,jobs and name really be sorted or just the result ?

Comment: Only result will be sorted. I've edited the answer so you can sort the existing arrays as well.

Comment: I am getting this error Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'NSDate' operands

Comment: Of course, my bad. I was using `Int` for testing purposes. I'll edit my answer. If you're using the extension I used before, you can just add `.day` so it converts it to an `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a programming problem instead of Swift problem.

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
let dateStrings = ["2016-03-02 01:04:42 +0000","2016-04-02 01:03:42 +0000" , "2016-05-02 01:03:42 +0000" ]
let date = dateStrings.map {
    dateString in formatter.dateFromString(dateString)}
let name = ["alex","john","danson"]
let job = ["programmer","engineer","swimmer"]

let combine = date.enumerate().map {
    index, date in
    return (date!,name[index],job[index])
    }

let result = combine.sort{
    $0.0.compare($1.0) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
}
```

Comment: Yours is correct either but how can i get the sorted name ,date and job from it  ?